# How do I save a .txt file to multiple paths from a list in python

Tags: python, file-writing

I am attempting to write a short piece of code which will allow me to write the serial number of a Raspberry Pi and the date/time into a text file. This information will be written to a USB stick every time it is plugged into my Raspberry Pi. This script will be used on multiple Raspberry Pi's with different USB sticks so I have been trying to be as general as possible because paths change, etc. between the pieces of hardware.

The first part of my script works fine:

```
    #import packages
    from datetime import datetime
    import os
    import os.path
    from shutil import copyfile

    usblist = [x for x in usblist if not x.startswith('SETTINGS')] #For some reason I have some folders starting with SETTINGS that I don't want to delete but simply ignore in my list

    #create a new list with the paths for each USB
    usbpathlist = os.path.abspath(usblist[0]),os.path.abspath(usblist[1]) #I will only have two USB sticks inserted at a time

    #for some reason my paths show as in the /home/ directory when it appears that they are mounted in /media/
    usbpathlist = [w.replace('home', 'media') for w in usbpathlist] #this fixes the paths
```

I then pull the information that is unique to the Raspberry Pi and the date/time and save them as variables

```
    def getserial():
        #Extract the serial number from the cpuinfo file
        cpuserial = "0000000000000000"
        try:
            f = open("/proc/cpuinfo", "r")
            for line in f.readlines():
                if line[0:6] == "Serial":
                    cpuserial = line[10:26]
                    f.close()
        except:
            cpuserial = "ERROR00000000000"
        return cpuserial

    rpi_serial = getserial()

    time_experiment = str(datetime.now())
```

Now I write this information as a text file

```
    with open("rpi_information.txt", "w") as rpi_information:
        rpi_information.write("Raspberry Pi Serial Number: " + rpi_serial + "\n") #Write the serial number
        rpi_information.write("Time written: " + time_experiment + "\n") #Write the date
        rpi_information.close()
```

Finally the problematic part of my script is where I try to save this file to the paths of my USB sticks that I have saved above as 'usbpathlist'

```
    for d in usbpathlist:
        copyfile(rpi_information, d)
```

From here is where my problem lies- I have spent quite a bit of time googling and searching this site but I have been unable to figure out how to save this file to each USB stick after it has been created. A lot of the information online suggests that I cannot actually save text files to multiple locations at once, but that seems unlikely. If I manually insert the path in front of "rpi_information.txt" above, it saves without issue. My problem is that because my USB sticks will be different, these paths will change so I don't think this is a good solution. The errors that I have been receiving from this last part of the script (as is probably expected) are:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "home/pi/test.py", line 55 in <module> #test.py is my filename
        copyfile(rpi_information, d)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 103, in copyfile
        if _samefile(src,dst):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 88, in samefile
        return os.path.samefile(src,dst)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 90, in samefile
        s1 = os.stat(f1)
    TypeError: argument should be string, bytes, or integer, not _io.TextWrapper
```

Ultimately, I would like to find a way to pass this file to both USB sticks without issue. I'd like to keep this information as a text file because I will want to refer to it later on another computer. Any insight into how to make this work would be appreciated or any comments on how to improve my code would also be appreciated. This is my first python script and my first question on StackOverFlow (even though I have lurked for years), so please go easy on me! I have read a lot of documentation about this issue as well so I'm just baffled. Thanks for your assistance in advance.

---EDIT---
User Vulcan below suggested that my error was a failure to include ".txt" in the copyfile function. I had tried this previously to no avail either. This unfortunately produces the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "home/pi/test.py", line 55 in <module> #test.py is my filename
        copyfile(rpi_information.txt, d)
    AttributeError: '_io.TextWrapper' object has no attribute 'txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error trace highlights your issue here: `argument should be string... not _io.TextWrapper`. When you call `copyfile(rpi_information, d)`, the `rpi_information` member is a file handle, rather than a file path, which one of the file types that `copyfile` expects. Pass the file name:

```
for d in usbpathlist:
    copyfile('rpi_information.txt', d)
```